# When i close thick box it is stop all flash video on that page

Tags: flash

I have one page which has one banner at top and one link to watch video.
This video is open in thick box. 
My problem is when i close that thick box when video is completed then it also stop all flash content on that particular page.
I have also added one code to display that flash object which is

```
function showHideFlash(s) 
{
    var f_Objects = document.getElementsByTagName("object");
    for (i = 0; i < f_Objects.length; i++) 
    {
//      f_Objects[i].style.display = "none";
        f_Objects[i].style.visibility = s;
    }
    var f_Embeds = document.getElementsByTagName("embed");
    for (i = 0; i < f_Embeds.length; i++) 
    {
//      f_Embeds[i].style.display = "none";
        f_Embeds[i].style.visibility = s;           
    }
}
```

Please help me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a javascript problem, not a Flash problem.

You are hiding/showing all EMBED- and OBJECT-tag objects on the page.  Just find the specific one you are looking for by giving the element or object an 'id'.  Pass that id value to the function, and turn it off specifically:

```
function showHideFlash(s, id) 
{
    var f_Objects = document.getElementsById(id);
    for (i = 0; i < f_Objects.length; i++) 
    {
      f_Objects[i].style.display = (s) ? "visible" : "none";
    }
}
```

(This function has not been tested.)